# How to handle nested JSON data using gorm and postgres?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I'm trying to implement a server which will except the JSON data from `Jitsi` module and save it in the `Postgres` DB. Below is the sample data that the server will receive from the `Jitsi` [module](https://github.com/jitsi-contrib/prosody-plugins/tree/main/event_sync#muc-room-destroyed).

**JSON data**

```
{
  "event_name": "muc-room-created",
  "room_name": "catchup",
  "room_jid": "catchup@conference.meet.mydomain.com",
  "created_at": 1625823996,
  "destroyed_at": 1625824035,
  "all_occupants": [
    {
      "name": "James Barrow",
      "email": "j.barrow@domain.com",
      "id": "00380324-a840-400d-880f-7ee0933b7556",
      "occupant_jid": "14f01c40-5195-4a4d-8efb-f58b49d18741@meet.mydomain.com/OWhl8jSh",
      "joined_at": 1625823996,
      "left_at": 1625824035
    }
  ]
}
```

Since the above JSON data is nested data hence I created multiple `struct` to handle and store this in the DB. Below is the snippet from `models.go` file.

**Models.go**

```
package models

import (
    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

type UserDetails struct {
    Name        string    `json:"name"`
    Email       string    `json:"email"`
    Id          uuid.UUID `json:"id" gorm:"unique; type:uuid; column:id; default:uuid_generate_v4(); not_null"`
    OccupantJid string    `json:"occupant_jid"`
    JoinedAt    int64     `json:"joined_at"`
    LeftAt      int64     `json:"left_at"`
}

type RequestData struct {
    EventName    string        `json:"event_name"`
    RoomName     string        `json:"room_name"`
    RoomJID      string        `json:"room_jid" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    StartedAt    int64         `json:"created_at"`
    DestroyedAt  int64         `json:"destroyed_at"`
    UserID       int64         `gorm:"unique; not_null"`
    AllOccupants []UserDetails `gorm:"foreignkey:UserID" json:"all_occupants"`
}
```

**Connection.go**

```
package connection

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/jitsi-event/models"
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type DB struct {
    SQL *gorm.DB
}

var dbConn = &DB{}

func SetupDB(db_host, db_user, db_name, db_password string, db_port int) *gorm.DB {

    conn_name := fmt.Sprintf(
        "host=%v port=%v user=%v dbname=%v password=%v sslmode=disable",
        db_host,
        db_port,
        db_user,
        db_name,
        db_password,
    )

    fmt.Println("Connecting to DB: ", conn_name)
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(conn_name), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error connecting to DB: ", err)
    }

    db.AutoMigrate(&models.RequestData{}, &models.UserDetails{})
    
    // Initialize the DB
    request_data := models.RequestData{}

    db.Create(&request_data)
    //db.Create(&models.UserDetails{})

    dbConn.SQL = db
    return db
}

// GetPostgresDB returns the instance of the DB
func GetPostgresDB() *gorm.DB {
    return dbConn.SQL
}
```

Now when I'm trying to start the server I'm getting below error.

**ERROR**

> [error] invalid field found for struct github.com/jitsi-event/models.RequestData's field AllOccupants: define a valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer/Scanner interface

Even I have added a `foreignKey:UserID` but still I'm getting the error.

Please help. I'm trying this to make work from last couple of days but still no success.

Comment: try AllOccupants []UserDetails `gorm:"foreignKey:Id;references:UserID" json:"all_occupants"`.

Comment: Thanks for responding @EminLaletovic. But still same error.

Comment: Is `RequestData` struct related to a table in your database?

Comment: yes, it is in the database.

Comment: @metatxn please check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
type UserDetails struct {
    ...
    Id          uuid.UUID `json:"id" gorm:"unique; type:uuid; column:id; default:uuid_generate_v4(); not_null"`
    ...
}

type RequestData struct {
    ...
    UserID       int64         `gorm:"unique; not_null"`
    AllOccupants []UserDetails `gorm:"foreignkey:UserID" json:"all_occupants"`
    ...
}
```

Problem is in the relationship column type:

In `User` Model id type is [`uuid.UUID`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/uuid#UUID) but in `RequestData` model the foreign key type is `int64` which is the cause of issue both the key must be of same type to solve the issue you can either change the `UserDetails` model `Id` type to `int64` or update `RequestData` model as below:

```golang
type RequestData struct {
    ...
    UserID       uuid.UUID     `gorm:"unique; not_null"`
    AllOccupants []UserDetails `gorm:"foreignkey:Id;references:UserID" json:"all_occupants"`
}
```